# Reducibility condition

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}_{q}$, show that $x^q -\alpha x - \beta$ is irreducible $\iff$ $\beta \ne 0, \alpha = 1$, and $q$ is prime. I am having trouble proving the forward direction. For the reverse direction, I know that $x^q-x-\beta$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$ but I am not sure how this implies irreducibility.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: That's a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378637/prove-implications-of-irreducible-polynomial